# Git signed commits - How to suppress "You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key..."

Tags: git, gnupg, git-commit

I changed my global Git configuration to sign all commits. I also use gpg-agent so that I don't have to type my password every time.

Now every time I make a new commit I see the following five lines printed to my console:

```
[blank line]
You need a passphrase to unlock the secret key for
user: "John Doe <mail@gmail.com>"
2048-bit RSA key, ID ABCDEF12, created 2016-01-01
[blank line]
```

Even worse, when I do a simple stash, this message is printed *twice*, needlessly filling my console (I assume for one for each of the two commit objects that are created).

Is there a way to suppress this output?

Answer (score 24, accepted):

This is more a gpg configuration issue than a git one.

Since you are using an agent, you could as a workaround add `no-tty` to your `gpg.conf`.

```
echo 'no-tty' >> ~/.gnupg/gpg.conf
```

(this seems [working even better than the `--batch` option](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/212953/7490))

Comment: This seems to make me unable to sign keys with `gpg --sign-key xxxxxxxx`

Comment: @XavierHo OK: ask a new question with your OS, Git version and exact setup which illustrates this issue.

Comment: I'm going to poke around first, setup a minimal test case perhaps. Thanks

Answer (score 11):

The accepted answer doesn't work for me for Git `version 1.8.3.1` on `Fedora 25`.

#### What worked ?

1. Check if `gpg-agent` is running by
   `$ gpg-agent`
2. Make sure `gpg-agent` has your passphrase in cache. To make sure it is there, sign any file in the current directory. If the passphrase was not in the cache, it will be asked now.
   `$ gpg -s any-file.txt`
3. Don't forget to delete the newly generated signed `any-file.txt.gpg`
   `$ rm any-file.txt.gpg`
4. Now, signing commits with Git will work now by taking the required passphrase from gpg-agent.
   `$ git commit -S -m 'my commit message'`

Comment: Intersting. It worked for me at the time I wrote it. Still, +1

Comment: Nice, the step `gpg -s any-file.txt` is good one to cache the passphrase!

Comment: You can save some effort by giving `gpg` a non-existent filename. It will still prompt for your password and cache it, but not generate any files